# DPLYR Left_Join returns NA values

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I already performed a few Left_join's in R and it all worked fine... But now im trying to merge these two df's and it returns NA volumes in the new added column.
This is the code I used. Tried merging df1 and df2 by columns Ticker and Date. Goal was to merge the hits column do df1...

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by=c("Ticker","Date"))

Date Close  Volume Ticker      Company.Name
       1: 2019-12-23 90.25 5907200   ABBV            AbbVie
       2: 2019-12-24 89.85 1798800   ABBV            AbbVie
       3: 2019-12-26 89.83 4066700   ABBV            AbbVie
       4: 2019-12-27 89.20 4087800   ABBV            AbbVie
       5: 2019-12-30 88.52 7014800   ABBV            AbbVie
      ---                                                  
    3791: 2020-12-16 31.09  593300    VIR Vir Biotechnology
    3792: 2020-12-17 32.56  575200    VIR Vir Biotechnology
    3793: 2020-12-18 30.71 5362400    VIR Vir Biotechnology
    3794: 2020-12-21 30.95  957500    VIR Vir Biotechnology
    3795: 2020-12-22 30.27  562600    VIR Vir Biotechnology

  

    Date Ticker hits
   1: 2020-01-05    JNJ   17
   2: 2020-01-12    JNJ   20
   3: 2020-01-19    JNJ   18
   4: 2020-01-26    JNJ   20
   5: 2020-02-02    JNJ   20
  ---                       
1016: 2020-11-22   VBIV    9
1017: 2020-11-29   VBIV   19
1018: 2020-12-06   VBIV   16
1019: 2020-12-13   VBIV   16
1020: 2020-12-20   VBIV   13

 

    Date Close  Volume Ticker      Company.Name hits
   1: 2019-12-23 90.25 5907200   ABBV            AbbVie <NA>
   2: 2019-12-24 89.85 1798800   ABBV            AbbVie <NA>
   3: 2019-12-26 89.83 4066700   ABBV            AbbVie <NA>
   4: 2019-12-27 89.20 4087800   ABBV            AbbVie <NA>
   5: 2019-12-30 88.52 7014800   ABBV            AbbVie <NA>
  ---                                                       
3791: 2020-12-16 31.09  593300    VIR Vir Biotechnology <NA>
3792: 2020-12-17 32.56  575200    VIR Vir Biotechnology <NA>
3793: 2020-12-18 30.71 5362400    VIR Vir Biotechnology <NA>
3794: 2020-12-21 30.95  957500    VIR Vir Biotechnology <NA>
3795: 2020-12-22 30.27  562600    VIR Vir Biotechnology <NA>
```

I'm new to R, so apologies if this is might be trivial, but I'm just unable to solve this problem. Search function couldn't help me, hope you can! thanks in advance
Tim

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame("Ticker" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "Date" = c("12.10.20", "19.09.12", "13.12.19"),
                  "Company Name" = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"))

df2 <- data.frame("Ticker" = c(1, 4, 3),
                  "Date" = c("12.10.20", "19.09.12", "13.12.19"),
                  "Abbrev" = c("A", "B", "C")
)

df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by=c("Ticker", "Date"))
```

Here I want to add the column `Abbrev` to the dataframe `df1`. What happens when the left join is performed, R will check each combination in `df1`s columns `Ticker` and `Date`. If there is the exact same combination in `df2` it will add the respective value from the other columns except from `Ticker` and `Date` to `df1`. But, if the combination in `df1` cannot be found in `df2`, then it will replace this row with `NA`, since there is no value available for this given combination.

Lets look at `df3` for an example.

```
  Ticker     Date Company.Name Abbrev
1      1 12.10.20          ABC      A
2      2 19.09.12          DEF   <NA>
3      3 13.12.19          GHI      C
```

Here we can see what happend. When we created `df1` we said that the values in the column `Ticker` are `1, 2, 3`, whereas in `df2` those values are `1, 4, 3` (the `date` column is the same). When we joined those two dataframes it had the combination `Ticker = 2` and `Date = 19.09.12`. But when we look at `df2` we cannot find any combination of those values. Hence, it joins a `NA`.

Regarding your specific problem. Ensure, that each combination of your `by` columns (i.e. `Ticker` and `Date`) in `df1` is also given  `df2`.

Comment: Hi Yannik, thanks for the long&detailed explanation!
"If there is the exact same combination in df2 it will add the respective value from the other columns except from Ticker and Date to df1". This is what I expected to happen, and where I struggle. There are actually a lot of Datapoints with the exact same combination in df2 but I get a NA return...

Comment: You are welcome! The combinations have to be unique, so maybe try and add more columns as identifier to it (e.g. `left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Ticker", "Date", "Name", "Abbrev")`